# Need Help for SQL MIN MAX Group By and AGGREGATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table like this :

```
+--------+--------+--------+------------+
| HOLEID |  FROM  |   TO   | ALTERATION |
+--------+--------+--------+------------+
| HOLEV2 | 0      | 132.6  | AA-LT-1    |
| HOLEV2 | 132.6  | 171.28 | ARG-1-MSI  |
| HOLEV2 | 171.28 | 177.65 | AA-LT-1    |
| HOLEV2 | 177.65 | 178.8  | AA-LT-1    |
| HOLEV2 | 178.8  | 213.9  | AA-LT-1    |
| HOLEV2 | 213.9  | 214.8  | AA-LT-1    |
| HOLEV2 | 214.8  | 216.8  | AA-LT-1    |
| HOLEV2 | 216.8  | 219.4  | ARG-2-Kaol |
| HOLEV2 | 219.4  | 219.9  | ARG-2-Kaol |
| HOLEV2 | 219.9  | 220.3  | ARG-2-Kaol |
| HOLEV2 | 220.3  | 220.8  | ARG-2-Kaol |
| HOLEV2 | 220.8  | 232.6  | ARG-2-Kaol |
| HOLEV2 | 232.6  | 249.45 | ARG-1-MSI  |
| HOLEV2 | 249.45 | 256.9  | ARG-1-MSI  |
| HOLEV2 | 256.9  | 265.7  | ARG-2-Kaol |
| HOLEV2 | 265.7  | 290.1  | ARG-1-MSI  |
| HOLEV2 | 290.1  | 294.85 | ARG-2-Kaol |
| HOLEV2 | 294.85 | 308.4  | ARG-1-MSI  |
| HOLEV2 | 308.4  | 310.35 | ARG-1-MSI  |
| HOLEV2 | 310.35 | 325    | ARG-1-MSI  |
| HOLEV2 | 325    | 331.12 | ARG-2-Kaol |
| HOLEV2 | 331.12 | 332.1  | ARG-2-Kaol |
| HOLEV2 | 332.1  | 333.1  | ARG-1-MSI  |
| HOLEV2 | 333.1  | 333.6  | ARG-1-MSI  |
| HOLEV2 | 333.6  | 353.6  | ARG-1-MSI  |
| HOLEV2 | 353.6  | 368.55 | ARG-1-MSI  |
| HOLEV2 | 368.55 | 376.6  | ARG-1-MSI  |
| HOLEV2 | 376.6  | 382.7  | ARG-1-MSI  |
| HOLEV2 | 382.7  | 396.1  | ARG-2-Kaol |
| HOLEV2 | 396.1  | 416.2  | ARG-1-MSI  |
+--------+--------+--------+------------+
```

I'm trying to Group by the ALTERATION value, beside Minimum(FROM) , maximum([TO]), maximum Id and group by the ALTERATION code.

Here is my query

```
SELECT MAX(Id) as Id,[HOLEID] as HOLEID,MIN([FROM]) AS [FROM],MAX([TO]) AS [TO],[ALTERATION] FROM (
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [FROM] ASC) AS Id,
[HOLEID]
      ,[FROM]
      ,[TO]
      ,[ALTERATION]
  FROM [dbo].[ALT]
  where [FROM] < 400
  )Z
  GROUP BY [ALTERATION],[HOLEID]
```

but the returning value not like I want to:

```
+----+--------+-------+-----------+------------+
| Id | HOLEID | FROM  |    TO     | ALTERATION |
+----+--------+-------+-----------+------------+
|  7 | HOLEV2 | 0     |     216.8 | AA-LT-1    |
| 30 | HOLEV2 | 132.6 | 416.2     | ARG-1-MSI  |
| 29 | HOLEV2 | 216.8 | 396.1     | ARG-2-Kaol |
+----+--------+-------+-----------+------------+
```

I want to be like this:

```
+-------+---------+-----------+---------------+
| maxId | minFROM |   maxTO   |  ALTERATION   |
+-------+---------+-----------+---------------+
|     1 |    0    |  132.6    | AA-LT-1       |
|     2 | 132.6   | 171.28    | ARG-1-MSI     |
|     7 | 171.28  | 216.8     | AA-LT-1       |
|    12 | 216.8   | 232.6     | ARG-2-Kaol    |
|    14 | 232.6   | 256.9     | ARG-1-MSI     |
|    15 | 256.9   | 265.7     | ARG-2-Kaol    |
|    16 | 265.7   | 290.1     | ARG-1-MSI     |
|    17 | 290.1   | 294.85    | ARG-2-Kaol    |
|    20 | 294.85  | 325       |     ARG-1-MSI |
|    22 | 325     |     332.1 | ARG-2-Kaol    |
|    28 | 332.1   | 382.7     | ARG-1-MSI     |
|    29 | 382.7   | 396.1     | ARG-2-Kaol    |
|    30 | 396.1   | 416.2     | ARG-1-MSI     |
+-------+---------+-----------+---------------+
```

I also used "SELECT DISTINCT" but it didn't work

Comment: (1) Why are you using unsupported software?  (2) What if there are gaps in the "from"/"to" time periods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-island problem, where you want to group together "adjacent" rows having the same `holeid` and `alteration`.

Here is on approach using window functions: the difference between row numbers can be used to define the groups.

```
select
    max(id) max_id,
    min([from]) min_from,
    max([to]) max_to,
    alteration
from (
    select 
        a.*,
        row_number() over(partition by holeid order by [from]) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by holeid, alteration order by [from]) rn2
    from dbo.alt a
) t
group by holeid, alteration, rn1 - rn2
order by min_from
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4a34168efb71f26129c1dcca7c56dcf3)**:

```
min_from | max_to | alteration
:------- | :----- | :---------
0.00     | 132.60 | AA-LT-1   
132.60   | 171.28 | ARG-1-MSI 
171.28   | 216.80 | AA-LT-1   
216.80   | 232.60 | ARG-2-Kaol
232.60   | 256.90 | ARG-1-MSI 
256.90   | 265.70 | ARG-2-Kaol
265.70   | 290.10 | ARG-1-MSI 
290.10   | 294.85 | ARG-2-Kaol
294.85   | 325.00 | ARG-1-MSI 
325.00   | 332.10 | ARG-2-Kaol
332.10   | 382.70 | ARG-1-MSI 
382.70   | 396.10 | ARG-2-Kaol
396.10   | 416.20 | ARG-1-MSI
```

Note: your sample data has no column `id` so this does not appear in the above results.

Comment: This will not wok if you change the 4th row's value from "HOLEV2 | 177.65 | 178.8  | AA-LT-1" to "HOLEV2 | 178.65 | 178.8  | AA-LT-1". But some how I feel your solution interesting and I learned something from this. 1+ for you :)

Comment: Thankyou. i wish i could give you a gold badge.